# Model not updated correctly on drag (Apartment + Vue + Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Stack used: Rails 6

Gems used: Apartment, Devise, Vue, vuedraggable, acts_as_list

I'm trying to create a "Trello" type app. Right now, I'm trying to implement `vuedraggable`.

So here is my problem: I have 3 List columns right now. I want to be able to drag each List column around, and update their position, so that when I refresh my page they keep the updated position. Right now, when I drag my columns it works great live, but the position modification isn't saved correctly. When I refresh my page, the columns take their inital position, so their position aren't saved correctly. I guess since I'm using `Apartment`, I'm not using the right method to save it.

Here is my Lists Controller :

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: %i[show edit update destroy move]

  def move
    @list.insert_at(list_params[:position].to_i)
    render action: :show
  end

  private

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :position)
  end
end
```

And here is my Vue component :

```
<template>
  <draggable v-model="lists" group=".lists" class="row dragArea" @end="listMoved">
    <div v-for="(list, index) in lists" class="col-3 mr-5">
      <h5>{{ list.name }}</h5>
      <hr />

      <div v-for="(card, index) in list.cards" class="card card-body mb-3">
        {{ card.name }}
      </div>

      <div class="card card-body">
        <textarea v-model="messages[list.id]" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <button v-on:click="submitMessages(list.id)" class="btn btn-secondary">Ajouter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script>
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
  components: {draggable},

  props: ['original_lists'],

  data: function() {
    return {
      messages: {},
      lists: this.original_lists
    };
  },

  methods: {
    listMoved: function(event) {
      var data = new FormData
      data.append("list[position]", event.newIndex + 1)
      Rails.ajax({
        beforeSend: () => true,
        url: `/lists/${this.lists[event.newIndex].id}/move`,
        type: "PATCH",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
      })
    },
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dragArea{
  min-height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

And here is what's logged in my terminal when moving (dragging) the first List column in third position:

```
Started PATCH "/lists/1/move" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-09 18:54:17 +0100
   (0.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  ↳ config/initializers/apartment/apartment.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "users"."subdomain" FROM "users"
  ↳ config/initializers/apartment/apartment.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
   (0.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by ListsController#move as JSON
  Parameters: {"list"=>{"position"=>"3"}, "id"=>"1"}
  List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:76:in `set_list'
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:68:in `move'
  List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?   [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:68:in `move'
  List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("lists"."position" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "lists"."position" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:68:in `move'
  List Update All (0.0ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "position" = ("lists"."position" - 1), "updated_at" = '2019-12-09 17:54:17.046407' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("lists".id != 1) AND ("lists"."position" > 1) AND ("lists"."position" <= 3)
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:68:in `move'
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:68:in `move'
  Rendering lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 85)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/shared/_header.html.erb:13
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.9ms | Allocations: 1584)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 10514)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "users"."subdomain" FROM "users"
  ↳ config/initializers/apartment/apartment.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
   (0.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
```

Comment: What does `insert_at` method?

Comment: `insert_at` is an `acts_as_list` method used to change position and reorder list! (https://github.com/brendon/acts_as_list)